# dlv substitute-path example in config.yml

Tags: go, debugging, delve

Any example to set from and to path in $HOME/.dlv/config.yml ? I have tried setting:

case 1 ( with quotes in from and to)
substitute-path:

```
{"from":
"/private/var/tmp/_bazel/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee"
"to": "/Users/xxx/code/src"}
```

case 2: ( without quotes in from and to)
substitute-path:

```
{from:
"/private/var/tmp/_bazel/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee"
to: "/Users/xxx/code/src"}
```

case 2: ( with hyphan before '{from' )
substitute-path:

```
-{from:
"/private/var/tmp/_bazel/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee"
to: "/Users/xxx/code/src"}
```

case 2: ( with hyphan before '{from' )
substitute-path:

```
-{"from":
"/private/var/tmp/_bazel/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee"
"to": "/Users/xxx/code/src"}
```

all 4 cases fails with config. error.
any working sample to set the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a space. The quotes are relevant only if the  values or keys have spaces in them, or some other non-printable, non-ascii characters.

The config here, without comments:

```
$ cat ~/.config/dlv/config.yml | sed '/^#/d; /^$/d'
aliases:
  # command: ["alias1", "alias2"]
substitute-path:
  - {from: /my/source/code/was/here, to: /but/now/its/here}
debug-info-directories: ["/usr/lib/debug/.build-id"]
```

Seems like valid yaml:

```
$ yq < ~/.config/dlv/config.yml 
{
  "aliases": null,
  "substitute-path": [
    {
      "from": "/my/source/code/was/here",
      "to": "/but/now/its/here"
    }
  ],
  "debug-info-directories": [
    "/usr/lib/debug/.build-id"
  ]
}
```

The yq tool is a wrapper for jq.

```
$ yq --help | sed 8q
usage: yq [options] <jq filter> [input file...]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]

yq: Command-line YAML processor - jq wrapper for YAML documents

yq transcodes YAML documents to JSON and passes them to jq.
See https://github.com/kislyuk/yq for more information.
```

Comment: Bazel full exe path 

/private/var/tmp/_bazel_xxx/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg/bin/src/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx_/xxxx
/src/code/path/tocodefile/

In ‘ from’ field full executable path needed or till /private/var/tmp/_bazel_xxx/d3eb9a0ef06857aebc54b41ff425d2ee/execroot/. 
Tried many combination of from and to dlv still shows no source found.