# How to source files for dlv golang core

Tags: go, dlv

I am trying to debug core in golang using delve.
However for, there is mismatch in directory when loading the backtrace

Instead of loading it as x/y/src/test/count.go it is loading it as x/y/test/count.go

Because of which I am not able to list the functions.
Is there a way to load it right path like gdb something like directory/source.

Comment: Ref: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/kJaVLLzEEaE

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? Which IDE you're using? Which OS? Dlv version?

Comment: Sorry for being late.
Using it on linux just normal terminal. 


Delve Debugger
Version: 1.1.0

Comment: Got it resolved via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919621/dlv-substitute-path-example-in-config-yml